# Embedded font error at PDFbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've tried to create a pdf document in java with pdfbox and everything works fine, but when I try to open my pdf I get the message that the embedded font could not be extracted correctly.What could be the reason?

Here I load my PDfont:

```
private PDFont getFont(PDDocument doc) throws IOException {
    return PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc, "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the order when `PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF()` matters. After putting it to the beginning of the processing code it started to work in my case.

<sub>But some other bugs popped(primarily with text encoding) up so I've switched the library anyway.</sub>

Comment: Perfect. This just fixed my problem also. I had loadTTF after I had created a new PDPageContentStream. I moved the call to before the PDPageContentStream creation and the error went away.